# Does robot framework support Python 3.x

Tags: robotframework

i can see online most of the videos and study materials are for robot framework with python 2.x, does robot framework support Python 3.x ?

Comment: I simple Google search would have found this for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. More up-to-date information here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework

Answer (score 5):

Robot Framework supports Python 3 since the release of it's [version 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46216782/8332700). If you're using an earlier version of Robot Framework, it will not support Python 3.x

Next thing to take into consideration is, while Robot Framework's core itself now supports Python 3, not all of it's ecosystem does yet! For example, someone recently had problems using PaBot due to Python 3 incompatibility (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46216782/8332700))

Fortunately, most of the ecosystem is slowly getting updated by it's great community. As a matter of fact, the Selenium library, which is one of the most used libraries most of the time, has recently been updated to [support Python 3](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/releases/tag/v3.0.0a2)

So, yes, Robot Framework does support Python 3.x, but not all of it's ecosystem does, so you should do an evaluation of your project's needs first before going with Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Robot Framework supports Python 3. For more info you can visit this url:https://pypi.org/project/robotframework/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20147358)

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal The answer is "Robot Framework supports Python 3", the link is just for supporting information.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that should be as a comment because this is not a actual answer supporting the question

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal It exactly answers the question, as the question is _"does robot framework support Python 3.x"_. The answer to that question is "yes it does". Sure, the OP should have refrained from posting because there is already an answer from last year that says exactly the same, but it is an answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the Robot Framework versions that Compatible for Python 3.x. PFB the details.
We need to install the mentioned version of python and also the mentioned version for all the PIP packaged  in sequence as mentioned below to work smoothly in Robot Framework Ride with Python 3.x

python 3.6.8...The
Chromedriver link:https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

```
1.wxPython==4.0.7.post2
2.decorators==0.1.1
3.setuptools-scm==3.3.3
4.selenium==3.141.0
5.robotframework==3.1.2
6.pywin32==227
7.Pypubsub==4.0.3
8.robotframework-ride==1.7.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does support python 3.x

I am using robot framework 3.2.1 with Python 3.7.4

You might need an IDE, for which you can either use RIDE or pycharm

Ride version 1.7.4.2